# Is my onboard sound card corrupted or does the audio work badly on ubuntu?

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

I have this same pc since 2011 and the audio has always worked fine, except until now (2020 - 2021) when it does not detect my sound card well. Lately I installed ubuntu 20.10 and it detects it when it wants, with pulseaudio -k it restarts and gives me sound but it almost never shows all the options like this, I need a lot of luck : [image: Bien como debería ser]

normally it looks like this, without microphone or input line:

[image]

I can record with audacity even if pulseaudio does not detect the input, this does not work for telegram, it is a 7.1 sound card, most of the time I have no input sound, other times it only recognizes up to 2.1 and almost always when turning on the pc it does not detect it at all. Is it my card that is damaged or has something changed in Ubuntu that supports it worse than before?

Chip: Realtek ALC887-VD.
Sorry for my English, translated by google.

Comment: A 12 year old computer may not run Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: @David Yes that works, and very well, like 10 years ago or even faster (ssd). It appears that computer development has not advanced as much as it is led to believe.